# Android QuickBlox - CustomObject Push to Array Field

Tags: quickblox

Hi I'm using CustomObject to bulid friends list but I'm facing below problem.
When I try to push a number to an array field it returns null value and the field is not updated but if I add it as a normal field (not pushing to array) it works fine.

Below is my code:

```
QBCustomObject friendsList = new QBCustomObject();
friendsList.setClassName("Friends");
HashMap<String, Object> fields = new HashMap<String, Object>();
fields.put("push[friendsId][]", "00001111");
friendsList.setFields(fields);
```

and logcat shows below api request:

```
https://api.quickblox.com/data/Friends.json?push[friendsId][]=00001111
```

but if I use below code it works but not append to array. It adds new record:

```
fields.put("friendsId", "00001111");
friendsList.setFields(fields);
```

Is there anything wrong with my way?

Comment: Can you provide the entire code request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update your record, your URL should look like

[https://api.quickblox.com/data/Friends/**id**.json?push[friendsId][]= 00001111](https://api.quickblox.com/data/Friends/%2a%2aid%2a%2a.json?push%5BfriendsId%5D%5B%5D=%2000001111),

where **id** is a record **id**.

For example,

[https://api.quickblox.com/data/Friends/**111c0ec5535c12669c000721**.json?push[friendsId][]= 00001111](https://api.quickblox.com/data/Friends/%2a%2a111c0ec5535c12669c000721%2a%2a.json?push%5BfriendsId%5D%5B%5D=%2000001111)

Did my answer helped you ?

Comment: I think this is the right answer, just try to set ID of record you would like to update: friendsList.setId(...);

Comment: Thank you but for the first time, I have no record Id! so, If I want to add two friends Id's to in one shot, I will not be able to do it. In this case I have to first insert the first one, then from the result listener, I will extract the Id and then use it to update the record with the new Id's. Is it like this?

Comment: Do you use Update or Create record request?

Comment: I use setField function, I don't know the code behind it is it update or create but it seems it always creates new record. see below link of the CustomObjectField: http://sdk.quickblox.com/android/com/quickblox/module/custom/model/QBCustomObjectField.html

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the whole record. Don't try to add an object separately into an array, update the whole record.